# box2d, which one of fixtures in contact is OTHER fixture?

Tags: c++, box2d

When I do

```
_body->GetContactList()->contact->GetFixtureA()
```

or

```
GetFixtureB()
```

is there any chance that B is always the other fixture? (not mine, not fixture of that _body I'm asking for contact list).

When I'm checking this in debugger - it is always B, but I haven't met exact info on that in box2d docs or elsewhere.

It's really boring to force my way through large hierarchy of my classes that I put in body UserData each time, for both of fixtures in this contact just to figure out which one of them is the other body.

Comment: This is not necessary. GetFixtureA can give any body at different time. It is possible that it give same body at every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

No.

**Long Answer**

I've confirmed that the following statement is ***not*** always true, at least in the version of Box2d that comes with the Cocos2D v2.1 distribution (2.2.1):

```
// Not always TRUE:
(_body->GetContactList()->contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody() == _body)
```

You can check this by creating a dummy contact listener:

```
#import "b2WorldCallbacks.h"

class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {
        b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
        b2Body *bodyA = fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyA_A = bodyA->GetContactList()->contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();

        NSLog(@"%p, %p, %p", fixtureA, bodyA, bodyA_A);

        b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
        b2Body *bodyB = fixtureB->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB_A = bodyB->GetContactList()->contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();

        NSLog(@"%p, %p, %p", fixtureB, bodyB, bodyB_A);
    }
};
```

You'll find that `bodyA_A == bodyB_A`, rather than `(bodyA == bodyA_A) && (bodyB == bodyB_A)`, as you've hypothesized. Sorry!